How do we create a materialized view with dbt in snowflake
How can we create a materialized view in Snowflake using dbt?
How can we create materialized View using dbt in snowflake? As far as I know we have 3 transformations View, table, incremenatal. Is there anything else? I have this requirement for my BI team they need this but creating view is taking a lot of time to run

Dbt supports 5 types of materialisations, one of which is materialized view: https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/build/materializations

check out the following. The final materialization is ephemeral - but I'm mentioning that just for completeness, you won't want to use that :)
https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/build/materializations#materialized-view
